# How to add a c# project as a resource in a class library c# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have been working on a class library that generates c# projects from an existing c# project. Right now I have the template project in a specific folder on my machine but what I really need is to add that template project to the class library as a resource, so I could distribute the dll. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: Isn't this just an ordinary reference?

Comment: Are you aware you can create visual studio project templates and make them available as a choice when starting a new solution?

Comment: @Crowcoder, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, and you're saying you've got a project that produces new C# projects (so .csproj and .cs files) and you want to add those as a resource, then I'd zip them up and add the zip as a resource.

Also have a look at the way new templates in Visual Studio are distributed. Within Visual Studios program files you'll find the built-in templates for example "C# Console Application" and "VB.NET WinForms" in the default path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates", however you can always download new ones from online and add them to Visual Studio, I'm guessing they could be zip or some form of packaged file.

There's information from Microsoft on how to create your own project templates and mentions about zipping them up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2017

There's also a guide here on how to create your own project templates https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/180/Create-custom-project-templates-in-Visual-Studio

Having a look around at distributed project templates, they mostly come from the Visual Studio Marketplace.

Comment: Could you include some links please?

Answer (score 0):

Video 18 of this series on the Microsoft Virtual Academy might help you.

Creating and Adding References to Assemblies
https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=Ry6jz0QIC_5706218949

Comment: Reference is different than Resource.

Comment: As @Crowcoder say, reference is different than Resource. Think in this project as a collection of files that I want to reproduce base on some call.